# Возникает ошибка в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возникает ошибка при клике на чекбоксы для вывода общей суммы

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLDivElement]input[name=''] :checked

в чём может быть проблема?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#type_site").change(function() {
        var typeOfSite = jQuery("#type_site :selected").val(),
            formOftype = jQuery("#config_site");

            /* Обнуляем общую и сумм с НДС в поле вывода */
            jQuery("#summ span").text("0");
            jQuery("#summ_nds span").text("0");

            /* Выбираем соответствующую форму из файла */
            formOftype.load("/services/developing/calculator/all/",{option:typeOfSite});

            /* Выбираем все чекбоксы которые были подгружены, в этом нам поможет функция live */
            formOftype.live("change",function() {

                /* При проведении действий пересчитываем сумму в зависимости от выбраных чекбоксов */
                var totalSum = 0, /* Полную сумму сначала приравниваем к нулю */
                    totalSumNDS = 0,
                    choiceCMS = parseInt(jQuery("#cms_radio :selected").val());

                    /* Приплюсовываем сумму стоимости CMS */
                    totalSum += choiceCMS;

                /* Каждое поле ввода проверяем на введеное значение, если больше нуля то считаем его */
                jQuery("#inputCell").each(function() {
                        var inputCell = parseInt($("#inputCell").val()) * parseInt(jQuery("#inputCell").attr("name"));
                        totalSum += inputCell ;
                });

                /* Пересчитываем все чекбоксы которые отмечены галочкой*/
                jQuery(this + "input[name=''] :checked").each(function() {
                        totalSum += parseInt(jQuery(this).val());
                    });

                /* Подсчет и вывод суммы итоговой */
                totalSumNDS = totalSum * 1.18 ;
                jQuery("#summ span").text(totalSum);
                jQuery("#summ_nds span").text(totalSumNDS);
            });
    }); 

});
```

Comment: Проблема с этой части кода: `jQuery(this + "input[name=''] :checked")` — зачем прибавлять `this`? jQuery использует строку с CSS-подобном выражением для нахождения элементов, а `this` выглядит как `[object HTMLDivElement]`, что явно не подходит.

Comment: Нужно либо заменить его на что-то осмысленное для jQuery, либо совсем убрать, если на странице лишь один подходящий элемент.

Comment: функция live давно устарела и была убрана из jQuery